# Access variable a method from another method

Tags: c#, variables

I have one small issue with a variable:

```
public class Ini
{
    private float euhh;

    public void ReceiveValues(Del ludel, int kont)
    {           
        dell[kont] = ludel;            
        euhh = dell[kont].euh;      
    }


    public string PaFa(int kont)
    {                        
        Console.WriteLine(euhh);         
        return euhh;
    }
}
```

I want to **send** the value of  dell[kont].euh (member of a struct) from ReceiveValues to PaFa. I tried this with a private variable euhh but when I print the value in console the value of euhh is 0.

Any advice please? Or maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Please tell me those are dummy names...

Comment: Show the relevant code where you use the class.

Comment: You would be calling PaFa before ReceiveValues

Comment: Maybe dell[kont].euh IS zero?

Comment: Wait, where is `hhh` coming from?

Comment: If I print euhh in ReceiveValues it has the right value. When i print it in PaFa its 0.

Comment: @ maurice it was a mistake: return euhh;

Comment: @Adil No, first i call ReceiveValues then PaFa

Comment: RIP naming conventions.

Comment: I think naming has nothing to do with my problem....

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming calling order of those two method. Why not simply returning the value for future use:

```
public class Ini
{
    public float ReceiveValues(Del ludel, int kont)
    {           
        dell[kont] = ludel;            
        return dell[kont].euh;      
    }


    public string PaFa(int kont, float euhh)
    {      
        euhh;       
        Console.WriteLine(euhh);         
        return hhh;
    }
}
```

and use it as:

```
float euhh = ReceiveValues(...);
string s = PaFa(..., euhh);
```

Comment: Because I have to call PaFa  from another method only with (int kont)